# git: difference of two separate branches

Tags: git, diff

I want to take a diff of all the files in two different branches. 
Let's say a project has 100 files and there are two teams working on two separate branches.
At some point I want to know that how much both the branches differ.
How can I do that? Is there a way to visualize the differences graphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `git diff <branchone> <branchtwo>`.

If you set the `diff.tool` configuration option, the tool name you give will be used for a graphical diff.